# how to determine max_client_conn for pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I'm sort of an "accidental dba" so apologies for a real noob question here. I'm using pgbouncer in **pool_mode = transaction** mode. Yesterday I started getting errors in my php log:

> no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)

I had **max_client_conn** = 150 to match **max_connections** in my postgresql.conf.

So my first question is, should pgbouncer max_client_conn be set equal to postgresql max_connections, or am I totally misunderstanding that relationship?

I have 20 databases on a single postgres instance behind pgbouncer with the default default_pool_size = 20. So should max_client_conn be 400? (pool_size * number_of_databases)?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html

> **max_client_conn** Maximum number of client connections allowed.
>
> **default_pool_size** How many server connections to allow per user/database pair.

so max_client_conn should be way larger then postgres `max_connections`, otherwise why you use connection pooler at all?..

If you have 20 databases and set default_pool_size to 20, you will allow pgbouncer to open 400 connections to db, so you need to adjust posgtres.conf `max_connections` to 400 and set pgbouncer `max_client_conn` to smth like 4000 (to have average 10 connections in pool for each actual db connection)

This answer is only meant to provide an example for understanding the settings, not as a statement to literally follow. (eg I just saw a config with:

```
max_client_conn = 10000
default_pool_size = 100
max_db_connections = 100
max_user_connections = 100
```

for cluster with two databases and max_connections set to 100). Here the logic is different, also mind `max_db_connections` is set and in fact connection limits are set individually per database in pgbouncer [database] section.

So - play with small settings to get the idea of how config influence each other - this is *"how to determine max_client_conn for pgbouncer"* the best

Answer (score 10):

Like almost everyone, then you are setting your pool size way to high. **Don't let your postgresql server do the connection pooling**. If you do then it severely hurts your performance.

The optimal setting for how many concurrent connection to postgresql is

```
connections = ((core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)
```

That means that if you are running your database on a 2 core server, then your total pool size from pgbouncer should be no more than 5. Pgbouncer is a lot better at handling pooling than postgresql, so let it do that.

So, leave the max_connections in my postgresql.conf to it's default 100 (no reason to change as it is a max. Also this should always be higher than what your application needs as some logging, admin and backup processes needs connections as well)

And in your pgbouncer.ini file set

```
max_db_connections=5
default_pool_size=5
max_client_conn=400
```

For more information https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/06/27/scaling-postgresql-with-pgbouncer-you-may-need-a-connection-pooler-sooner-than-you-expect/

Comment: Does everyone understand what "effective_spindle_count" stands for ?